# jQuery highlight td if it's not the same as another td on the same row

Tags: jquery, indexing, html-table

What I need to do is add a class to the first column td if the data inside matches the data inside of the third column td on the same row.

http://jsfiddle.net/rUssu/

html table

```
<table border="1">
   <tr><th>first</th><th>second</th><th>third</th></tr>
   <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>3</td></tr>
   <tr><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>9</td></tr>
 </table>
```

javascript/jquery

```
var cPrice = $('th').filter(':contains("first")');
var cDefault = $('th').filter(':contains("third")');

cp = cPrice.index() + 1;
cd = cDefault.index() + 1;

$('table td:nth-child(' + cp + ')').filter(function () {
   //alert($(this).text());
   var temp = $(this).index() + 2;
   //alert(temp);

   return $(this).text() != $('table td:eq('+ temp +')').text();
}).addClass("boom");
```

css

```
th{padding:5px;}
td{text-align:center;}
.boom{color:red;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/rUssu/1/

```
return $(this).text() != $(this).nextAll().eq(1).text();
```

Your selector was getting the temp'th TD of ALL TDs not just the ones in the current row.

Comment: This answer is adding the class to all cells which do **not** match but OP wanted to add the class to all cells which **do** match. I think you need to change the `!=` to a `===`

Comment: @ArrayKnight, thanks. I've never heard of the nextAll function.  I'll also look into that when i get back to work tomorrow.

Comment: I ended up using nextAll.  I tried both ways and they both work great.  I chose to use nextAll because the counting eq() started at the (this) td instead of starting back at the beginning of the row of the table. Not sure which is faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through each row individually and compare cell 1 to cell 3, similar to this:

```
$('table tr').each(function () {
    var $firstCell = $('td:eq(0)', this);
    var $thirdCell = $('td:eq(2)', this);

    if($firstCell.text() === $thirdCell.text()){
        $firstCell.addClass('boom');
    }
})
```

**Edit**

After looking at your code again, I believe using [**siblings()**](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) of the current cell should work too, similar to this:

```
$('table td:nth-child(' + cp + ')').filter(function () {
      return $(this).text() === $(this).siblings().eq(1).text();
}).addClass("boom");
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8SHqU/) - compare current cell with second next sibling

---

Comment: I knew about the each function but didn't want to go that route.  I'll look into siblings more when I get to work tomorrow. Thanks Francois